Autocorrelation between second order terms in Gaussian process
Suppose $\left\{Y_t\right\}$ is a zero-mean Guassian process, whose autocorrelation function (ACF) and partial autocorrelation function (PACF) at lag $k$ are denoted by $\rho_k$ and $\pi_k$ respectively.
An exercise ask to show that
$\operatorname{Corr}\left(Y_t^2, Y_{t-k}^2\right)=\left[\operatorname{Corr}\left(Y_t, Y_{t-k}\right)\right]^2=\rho_k^2$;
I have no idea about how to process the auto correlation between the second order terms, can anyone help me?
By the way, there is a following exercise to show $\pi_k=\operatorname{Corr}\left[Y_t^2, Y_{t-k}^2 \mid Y_{t-1}, \cdots, Y_{t-k}\right]$.

A strategy is the following: we find $a$ such that $Y_t-aY_{t-k}$ is independent of $Y_{t-k}$. Then
$$
\operatorname{Cov}\left(Y_t^2,Y_{t-k}^2\right)=\operatorname{Cov}\left(\left(Y_t-aY_{t-k}+aY_{t-k}\right)^2,Y_{t-k}^2\right).
$$
Then we expand the square.
